# lit() function missing in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think the `pyspark.sql.functions.lit()` function is missing from PySpark.

First noticed when I tried to import it. I also checked the source code, and couldn't find it. Just wanted to check here first if I'm correct there's a bug at all.

Finally, does anyone know how I can create a literal column from a string input, preferably with a lambda function?

Comment: I didn't execute the code because I am using PyDev and it gave an error on the import line. But now that you asked it ocurred to me that it probably was a PyDev bug, and I simply executed the code and it worked. Sorry for your time. Just a though though: I checked out the scala source and noticed that it simply creates a new `Column` object with the literal object. So I tried in python by using `Column(string)` but apparently it cannot be a string. I'm new in python too, so is this not the way I would create a Column object with a string to initialize?